# What is a Color4 property?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Sometimes various 3D object models (NIF files) will have a color property defined. They consist of 8 hexadecimal digits. For example:

```
#9aceff59
```

I could assume that fourth integer (place 7 and 8) is used to represent the transparency of a color, but would rather hear from someone who knows more about 3D objects. Also, what is the common valid range for setting this parameter?

Comment: This is likely to be closed since Arqade is for playing games, and design (including modding) is generally off-topic. If you haven't already asked at the official Bethsoft modder forum, then you should try there. The cutting edge of TES modding knowledge is with the people there, and they tend to stay within that forum and not show up here.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's the second time for me. I keep forgetting that this site is not about the technical aspect of games.

Comment: In addition to @kalina's answer, the range should be from `00` to `ff` (i.e. 0 to 255), with `ff` being completely opaque and `00` being completely transparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption, the fourth set of values is for specifying alpha as follows;

```
# red, green, blue, alpha
```

With values of `00` (0) to `ff` (255) for each value.

Comment: With values ranging from 00 (0) to ff (255) for each component. A high number means more of that component, meaning ff for alpha is opaque (not see-through at all) and 00 is invisible/completely transparent.